# iphone how to disable scrolling of tableview cells

Tags: iphone

i have 4 rows in my `table view` as a  home screen. First I want to disable scrolling of cells `up` and `down`. Secondly, I want to put a logo image to the 4th cell.

Can anyone suggest me right way to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

to disable scrolling use

```
tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

and in cellForRowAtIndexPath method

use this code snippet after cell has been created

```
if(indexPath.row == 3) {
  cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nameOfImage.png"];
}
```

Comment: sorry mate but image row function is not working. it does not show any issue but it is not loading image at row 4th or anywhere

Comment: did you add image in your application resources? replace image name with your desired image name

Comment: you don't need to call [cell.contentView addSubview:image]; this line will display image cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nameOfImage.png"]; every default cell has one ImageView already.

Comment: yes mate i have used image from my project. and tried your way. i does not show any error but it does not load image as well.

Comment: well mate try this UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"]; then cell.imageView.image = img; an dtry to debug your app and see if img is nil or allocated? else send me your code I'll solve the issue and send it back to you. My mail address is rahul.vyas.09@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

```
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO
```

For adding image to your cells, go to the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and create `UIImage` and add them them as subviews to your cells.

```
 if (indexPath.row ==3)
    // allocate your image 1
   [cell.contentView addSubview: image1];

 // and so on.
```

**Edit :**

Just try this.

```
UIImageView *sampleImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.jpg"]] autorelease];
sample.frame = CGRectMake(20, 10, 75, 75);
[cell addSubview:sampleImage];
```

Comment: Thanks mate it works. do you know how to put image in 4th cell.

Comment: use (indexPath.row ==4), add image as a subView to or use `cell.imageView.image`

Comment: i am using this code      if(indexPath.row == 4) {
        
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"location.png"];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:image];
        
    } but not working